# Query regarding a transformation of continuous random variables question

Tags: self-study, distributions, random-variable, joint-distribution

I have a query related to a transformation of variables question; the images of which I have attached here.

I have solved the question almost, but there seems to be a problem with the distribution that I have derived in the last line of the solution.

I would greatly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

N.B.: In the question, $U$ should follow $N(\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{4} = 0.25)$.

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

Comment: My post here seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2647462/321264.

Comment: Hi @StubbornAtom. Thanks for the link.

Can you please explain as to why the transformation (x,y) -> (u,v) not one-to-one ?
Also, we are mapping from X and Y. Why have you considered here -X and -Y ?

Comment: Check the general change of variables (transformation) formula.

Comment: The mapping is not one to one precisely because you get two values of $x,y$ when written in terms of $u,v$ (i.e. two preimages).